# how to write test class for methods with API calls?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

class :- facebook_API

```
public class facebook_API
{
public static HttpResponse getpermissionresponse(String accesstoken) 
{
    Http http =new Http();
    String flagpermit ='true';
    HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token='+accesstoken);         
    req.setmethod('GET');
    return http.send(req);
}
public static HttpResponse getownprofileresponse(String accesstoken) //done
{

   Http http =new Http();
   HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
   req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture&access_token='+accesstoken);
   req.setmethod('GET');
   return http.send(req);
}
public static void getpermission(String accesstoken)
{
    if((accesstoken!='')&&(accesstoken!=null))
    {
        HttpResponse res;
        res= facebook_API.getpermissionresponse(accesstoken);
        if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
        {            
            list<facebookpermission.Data>  objpermission = new list<facebookpermission.Data>();
            MBT_SFFB.facebookpermission objfacebookuserpermission = new MBT_SFFB.facebookpermission();
            objfacebookuserpermission=MBT_SFFB.facebookpermission.parse(res.getBody());
            list<String> scopes = new list<String>();
            list<String> granted_scopes = new list<String>();
            scopes.add('user_friends');
            scopes.add('email');
            scopes.add('manage_pages');
            scopes.add('publish_pages');
            scopes.add('business_management');
            scopes.add('public_profile');
            if(objfacebookuserpermission.data.size()>0)
            {
                objpermission =objfacebookuserpermission.data;                
                for(facebookpermission.Data objpermit:objpermission )    
                {
                    if(objpermit.status=='granted')
                    {
                        granted_scopes.add(objpermit.permission);
                    }
                }
                if(scopes.equals(granted_scopes))
                {
                    // permitted
                    facebook_API.getownprofile(accesstoken); // calls the profile 
                }               
            }           
        }    
    }
}
public static String getownprofile(String accesstoken)
{   
    if((accesstoken!='')&&(accesstoken!=null))
    {
        // call the Facebook API.       

        HttpResponse res = facebook_API.getownprofileresponse(accesstoken);           
        MBT_SFFB.facebookuserprifile objfacebookuser = new MBT_SFFB.facebookuserprifile();
        objfacebookuser=facebookuserprifile.parse(res.getBody());
        if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            // calling the facebook API for facebook pages -> calling the facebook api for pagespost. 
        }
    }
}
}
```

class socialsetup

```
Public class socialsetup
{
     public socialsetup()
     {
         facebook_API.getpermission('XXXXXXXX accesstoken XXXXXXXX');
     }
}
```

Test class for facebook_API

```
@IsTest
public class facebook_API_Test {
@isTest static void testfbpost() {

String jsontestgetownprofile = '{'+
    '  \"id\": \"1150203231712395\",'+
    '  \"name\": \"Neha Patel\",'+
    '  \"picture\": {'+
    '    \"data\": {'+
    '      \"is_silhouette\": false,'+
    '      \"url\": \"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13658929_1039496126116440_8074761323685568213_n.jpg?oh=f8c80920c7291d445fd5200c17a023bd&oe=59039402\"'+
    '    }'+
    '  }'+
    '}';

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGeneratorforprofile());
    HttpResponse res8 = facebook_API.getownprofileresponse('EAACsddsdssdfdfdsEdEose0cBAPortTucJLxiZBOUtgWmZCeJ7mYeBGBxVhXDaEnZBSMh2KPTzhDN2Hrp2vZCnZAYhKyxEuMb5B1QJ3r2ZCaWcwgRUsz9D8bNa10XSuhkAPHYEiHUtRzeheubZAqWzetB5jsGBACsM9IuZB4qsQNteDXIjANtJZCSGIijNyk6LDxYlQHVTpkBYFX4ZD');

    // Verify response received contains fake values
    String contentType8 = res8.getHeader('Content-Type');
    System.assert(contentType8 == 'application/json');
    String actualValue8 = res8.getBody();
    String expectedValue8 = jsontestgetownprofile;
    System.assertEquals(actualValue8, expectedValue8);
    System.assertEquals(200, res8.getStatusCode());

   String jsontestgetpermission = '{'+
    '  \"data\": ['+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"user_friends\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
    '    },'+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"email\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
    '    },'+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"manage_pages\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
    '    },'+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"publish_pages\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
    '    },'+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"business_management\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
    '    },'+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"public_profile\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
    '    },'+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"publish_actions\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"declined\"'+
    '    }'+
    '  ]'+
    '}';

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGeneratorforpermission());
   HttpResponse res2 = facebook_API.getpermissionresponse('EAACsddsdssdfdfdsEdEose0cBAPortTucJLxiZBOUtgWmZCeJ7mYeBGBxVhXDaEnZBSMh2KPTzhDN2Hrp2vZCnZAYhKyxEuMb5B1QJ3r2ZCaWcwgRUsz9D8bNa10XSuhkAPHYEiHUtRzeheubZAqWzetB5jsGBACsM9IuZB4qsQNteDXIjANtJZCSGIijNyk6LDxYlQHVTpkBYFX4ZD');

    // Verify response received contains fake values
   String contentType2 = res2.getHeader('Content-Type');
   System.assert(contentType2 == 'application/json');
   String actualValue2 = res2.getBody();
   String expectedValue2 = jsontestgetpermission;
   System.assertEquals(actualValue2, expectedValue2);
   System.assertEquals(200, res2.getStatusCode());
  }
 }
}
```

How to write Test class for facebook API as well as SocialSetup  classes?

Comment: in case of test class :- how to write testcode for 2 API response using mock class ?? as i found in Docs there is one method of HttpCalloutMock Interface that is Respond() that returns only one HttpResponse at a time. My case is one API call success makes another API call in single method

Answer (score 1):

In your mock class you can send multiple response based on the request body using
if-else. for more detail you can go through [HttpCalloutMock Interface where there is more than 1 callout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13395/httpcalloutmock-interface-where-there-is-more-than-1-callout)